# Find Numbers that Start with 31 and End with 21 on the given Interval

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I am looking for a function (with integer / math operation, instead of string) that would determine whether input number starts with 31 and end with 21.

For example, given array of integers below:

{ 341521, 513135, 434632, 312321, 315364, 312421 }

The function should return 312321 and 312421.

I still don't have it completed, but here's what I have so far (C#):

```
public bool IsValidId(int input)
{
    var result = input >= 310000 && input < 320000;

    if (result)
    {
        // Check for anything ending with 21, maybe something like
        // var endWith = (double) ((input / 21) / 100);
        // then check if endWith has decimal..
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show us what code you have written so far.  What tests does it fail?

Comment: I would guess that no library has this specific of a method available, why don't you write one?

Comment: The question sounds like it's going to need a custom mathematical function. I recommend asking it on [Math Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: *Any solution with strong-typed language is welcomed* **this IS NOT how this site works**. You **must** post what you have tried to solve this and explain to us what's your specific programming issue. If you only have an assignment and posting it here for us to solve it, then you're in the wrong place.

Comment: @ParasDPain, thanks for the input, I did asking it on Math Exchange, but haven't got satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be acheived quite simply using strings by using `startsWith` and `endsWith` but if you dont want to use strings at all you can keep find the digit in a number using the `Math.log10` and `Math.pow` functions. I would try to explain the use of these functions but my mathematics nomenclature is so rusty I'm certain I will fail horribly. I commented to code to explain the uses of the variables.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int [] checks = new int[] { 341521, 513135, 434632, 312321, 315364, 312421 };
    for(int check : checks) {
        System.out.println(check + " " + startsWithEndsWith(check, 31, 21));
    }
}

public static boolean startsWithEndsWith(int value, int startWithNumber, int endsWIthNumber) {
    // get the number of digits for each of our inputs
    int numValueDigits = (int) Math.log10(value);
    int numStartsDigits = (int) Math.log10(startWithNumber);
    int numEndsDigits = (int) Math.log10(endsWIthNumber);

    // if the value doesnt have as many digits as either our starting or ending numbers then its impossible to be true
    if(numValueDigits < numStartsDigits || numValueDigits < numEndsDigits) {
        return false;
    }

    // for each of our startWithNumber digits check if the number in the value matches the corrisponding number in the startsWithNumber
    for(int i=0;i<=numStartsDigits;i++) {
        if(getDigitAt(value, numValueDigits-i) != getDigitAt(startWithNumber, numStartsDigits-i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // for each of our endsWithNumber digits check if the number in the value matches the corrisponding number in the endsWithNumber
    for(int i=0;i<=numEndsDigits;i++) {
        if(getDigitAt(value, i) != getDigitAt(endsWIthNumber, i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // nothing failed therefore its valid
    return true;
}

/**
 * returns the digit at the specified location, starting at 0 would be the 1's place. Returns 0 if the location is higher than the number
 * @param num
 * @param location 0<=location<=9
 * @return
 */
private static int getDigitAt(int num, int location) {
    // divide our number by 10^location to make the digit at the location
    // be in the 1's position, then modulus that by 10 to extract the digit
    return (int) (num/Math.pow(10, location)) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the n-th digit of a number by dividing its remainder with 10^n by 10^(n-1) and you take the integer part (~math.floor).

```
int((3123 % 10^4) / 10^3) = 3
int((3123 % 10^3) / 10^2) = 1
int((3123 % 10^2) / 10^1) = 2
int((3123 % 10^1) / 10^0) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop for all numbers, each of them use O(1) to check if they fulfill the conditions: Let C be the current number

1. C%100 == 21
2. Let d = floor(log(C) + 1), if (d-2 >= 0 && C/10^(d-2) == 31)

If C fulfills both conditions, then it is one of the 31*21 number

Of course, why not just use string to check C[0,1] == "31" && C[len-2, len-1] == "21"?